# compilador de C++ para windows 10

Tags: c++, c, compilador

Estoy buscando un compilador que soporte las instrucciones `clrscr`, he leido que al parecer el error esta en la biblioteca `conio.h`.

He probado el `mingw` pero me da el siguiente error:

> C:\tesisv3>gcc sumar2.c
>   C:\Users\Yept\AppData\Local\Temp\ccb5dlGC.o:sumar2.c:(.text+0xe):
>   undefined reference to `clrscr' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1
>   exit status

el programa que quiero compilar es este:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h>
void main()

{

 int a,b,suma;

 clrscr();

 printf("Dame el primer numero \n");

 scanf("%d",&a);

 printf("Dame el segundo numero \n");

 scanf("%d",&b);

 suma=a+b;

 printf("El resultado de la suma es: %d \n",suma);

 getch();

}
```

he corrido el programa en un IDE que tengo que se llama *Turbo C++* pero no he podido utilizar su compilador desde el CMD para compilar pues me da un error el cual dice que no puede ser ejecutado en sistemas de 64 bits

Comment: yo tengo windows 10 y uso el codeblocks con su mingw y anda perfectamente

Comment: ¿Qué haces usando Turbo C++ en pleno 2018? xd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Estoy buscando un compilador que soporte las instrucciones clrscr

Esta función es exclusiva del compilador Turbo C++ (el mismo que comentas en tu pregunta), luego si realmente la necesitas tendrás que recurrir a este compilador. Como esta función no forma parte del estándar nadie te garantiza que el código vaya a compilar ni con otro compilador diferente ni, mucho menos, en otro sistema operativo.

> he corrido el programa en un IDE que tengo que se llama Turbo C++ pero no he podido utilizar su compilador desde el CMD para compilar pues me da un error el cual dice que no puede ser ejecutado en sistemas de 64 bits

Turbo C++ es un compilador descontinuado, es decir, que ya no recibe ni mantenimiento ni actualizaciones. Por si esto no fuera suficiente, hace unos años hubo un cambio general en los PCs, que pasaron de 32 a 64 bits...

Me temo que para que funcione tendrás que montarte una máquina virtual o jugar con el [modo de compatibilidad](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/15078/windows-make-older-programs-compatible) de Windows